# Not disabling Entire row in table in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have written a function which disables entire row based on some condition but for me the date fields are not getting disabled. Please help me in corecting it.

Calling from here

```
var rowCount = document.getElementById("BLK_CLVWS_COMPSCH").tBodies[0].rows.length;
        if(rowCount > 0)
        {
            for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++)
            {
                if ((document.getElementById("BLK_CLVWS_COMPSCH").tBodies[0].rows[i].cells[20].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].value)=='N')
                    fnDisablesch(i);
            }
        }
```

Function is

```
function fnDisablesch(z)
{
        var tblEventRef = document.getElementById("BLK_CLVWS_COMPSCH").tBodies[0];
    var rowRef      = tblEventRef.rows;


        rowRef[z].cells[0].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].disabled = true;
        rowRef[z].cells[1].getElementsByTagName("SELECT")[0].disabled = true;
        rowRef[z].cells[2].getElementsByTagName("SELECT")[0].disabled = true;
        rowRef[z].cells[3].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].disabled = true;
        rowRef[z].cells[3].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].nextSibling.style.visibility="hidden";
                    rowRef[z].cells[4].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].disabled = true;
        rowRef[z].cells[5].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].nextSibling.disabled = true;
        rowRef[z].cells[6].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].nextSibling.disabled = true;
        rowRef[z].cells[7].getElementsByTagName("SELECT")[0].disabled = true;
        rowRef[z].cells[8].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].nextSibling.disabled = true;
        rowRef[z].cells[9].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].disabled = true;
        rowRef[z].cells[10].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].nextSibling.disabled = true;
        rowRef[z].cells[11].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].nextSibling.disabled = true;
        rowRef[z].cells[12].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].nextSibling.disabled = true;
        rowRef[z].cells[13].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].nextSibling.disabled = true;
        rowRef[z].cells[14].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].nextSibling.disabled = true;
        rowRef[z].cells[15].getElementsByTagName("SELECT")[0].disabled = true;
        rowRef[z].cells[16].getElementsByTagName("SELECT")[0].disabled = true;
        rowRef[z].cells[17].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].disabled = true;
        rowRef[z].cells[18].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].disabled = true;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this can help?

this enables/disables everything inside the row itself, generates some fake data to play with

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Disable Row</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function setState(element, state) {
    element.disabled = state;
    var children = element.children, i;
    if (children === null || children.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      setState(children[i], state);
    }
  }

  function setRowState(tableid, index, state) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableid);
    if (!table) {
      return;
    }
    var row = table.rows[index];
    if (!row) {
      return;
    }
    setState(row, state);    
  }

  function generateData(tableid) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableid);
    if (!table) {
      return;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
      var row = document.createElement(i === 0 ? 'th' : 'tr');
      for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        var cell = document.createElement('td');
        if (i == 0) {
          cell.innerHTML = 'header ' + j;
          row.appendChild(cell);
          continue;
        }
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'text';
        if (j % 3 === 0) {
          input.type = 'date';
        }
        if (j % 4 === 0) {
          input.type = 'button';
        }
        cell.appendChild(input);
        row.appendChild(cell);
      }
      table.appendChild(row);
    }
  }

  function activate(tableid, text) {
    var el = document.getElementById(text).value;
    setRowState(tableid, parseInt(el), false);
  }

  function deactivate(tableid, text) {
    var el = document.getElementById(text).value;
    setRowState(tableid, parseInt(el), true);
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:generateData('fakedata');">
<input id="rowToUpdate" value="5" /><button id="activate" onclick="javascript:activate('fakedata', 'rowToUpdate');">Activate</button><button id="deactivate" onclick="javascript:deactivate('fakedata', 'rowToUpdate');">Deactivate</button>
<table id="fakedata">
</table>
</body>
</html>
```